# iFrame click monitoring from parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, dom-events, cross-domain

We have a client who needs us to include a tool in their site via iFrame.  Within the iFrame, we are displaying products and when the "add to cart" link is clicked, it needs to add the product to the parent documents cart.  The parent and child are not on the same domain.  Unfortunately, the client can't provide us with a method to post to the cart and all we can do is call their `cart.add(qty,id)` function, but it won't work within the iFrame because the iFrame obviously doesn't have the function available.  In addition, we can't just fake the post to cart as we can't access the session id.  Luckily I can add whatever Javascript I need to their main page.

Is there a way for me to listen for clicks in the iFrame from the parents, then to pull the quantity and product id values from within the iframe, then execute the `cart.add` function?  Is there a better way to approach this given the constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a method.  I wrote a post to explain here: http://blog.igodigital.com/blog/notes-on-cyber-weekend-targeted-email-campaigns/enabling-cross-domain-js-with-iframes-the-fun-way

Comment: Hi Brad, glad to know you figured it out, but now the link is dead. Can you please provide an updated link? Thanks!

Comment: Damn, it looks like the company I wrote the post for was acquired and their site and blog were shut down :(

Comment: Thanks to archive, I located it!!  https://web.archive.org/web/20130403073354/http://blog.igodigital.com/blog/notes-on-cyber-weekend-targeted-email-campaigns/enabling-cross-domain-js-with-iframes-the-fun-way

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible as it's a security risk and is prevented by the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 0):

dont use an iFrame. use jquery .load() to place the whole other site within a div. Make sure your "clicks" are live() so they catch clicks on the added content and it should be fine. I dunno how huge the site your loading in is. Also with load you can specify just a chunk of the page to bring in so just  or a specific div if you don't need all the header info.

Comment: jQuery.load() won't work as that also is restricted by the same origin policy (as stated in the API docs on jQuery under additional notes - http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: You can actually use jQuery.load as long as you include the cross domain Ajax plugin.  However, the problem is that the other "site" is actually a full Rails app.  When I tried this method before, it became a huge pain because you then need to move all of the js logic outside of the app and into the main frame... Huge headache.

Comment: dur sorry. Wasn't thinking about the cross domain thing. It's hardly an elegant solution but I don't know that there can be an elegant solution to such an inelegant request. :/

Comment: Tell me about it, haha... I think if we get them to add a CNAME record to the tool url then we can avoid the cross domain problems and host via iframe still.